#5 - token program: initialize account (program error: "incorrect program id") why
So i have a token that was created for me by a team. When i try and go to raydium to get an openbook market id this pops up #5 - token program: initialize account (program error: "incorrect program id") why is this happening. And what needs to be fised so it can work

The error occurs because your token was created with the Token-2022 program, but Raydium or OpenBook only supports the standard Token Program (spl-token); you need to either create a new token using the standard program or check if the application supports Token-2022.
You can read more about it here
Standard Token Program (spl-token) Documentation: https://spl.solana.com/token
Token-2022 Program Documentation: https://spl.solana.com/token-2022
